# Google Sheets wrong value of multiplication and division

Tags: google-sheets

I have 4 cells, O4, P4, Q4 and R4:

| O4 | P4 | Q4 | R4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.7 | = (O4+P4+Q4)*10 |

The result should be 37 but Google Sheets returns 30.1. If I write /10 instead of *10, I get 24.2 but it should be 0.37. What went wrong there?

Comment: Likely, the values in O4, P4 and Q4 aren't actually 1.0, 1.0 and 1.7; you are just seeing that due to formula setup or formatting (meaning the real, full numbers behind the formatting are different). The only way for anyone to know for sure is if you share a link to the sheet (or to a copy of the sheet), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: @ErikTyler: Unfortunately, the sheet contains private information so I am not allowed to share it, but I will try to create an MWE.

Comment: I see you were able to resolve the issue and that, in fact, it was that what you were seeing... wasn't what Google Sheets was seeing. To close this thread, please mark your own answer post as "Best Answer." As odd as that seems, this is the best way for contributors to know at a glance that an issue has been resolved and for future site visitors to quickly find the most relevant answers.

Comment: @ErikTyler: I already tried that, but I get the error "You can accept your own answer in 21 hours" so I have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ErikTyler, I found that the value displayed as "1.7" was actually a "01/07/2021". I have no idea why the sum is still correct but the multiplication isn't and why Google Sheets interprets it as such but at least I could fix the error by changing it to a real "1.7".